# Filter activities with permission requirements

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to let the user choose an application that my app should send a specific intent to. To get the list of candidates, `queryIntentActivities()` mostly works, except some applications define the accepting activity with a `permission` requirement, so I can't really start them. So, can I filter them out in any of these ways?

- Have `PackageManager` filter them out for me.
- From a `ResolveInfo`, check if the activity (or its parent application) requires a permission, so that I could check it with `checkSelfPermission()`.
- Start the activity picker (which filters them since Android 4.1) and somehow get the activity that was picked.

Comment: That is a bug in those applications. Never have an exported activity with an `<intent-filter>` that is also secured by a permission. `PackageManager` will not filter them out for you -- I once argued that it should, and I was shot down by Google engineers. Your second approach might work, though `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` is not the right answer. Use `checkSelfPermission()`. The caller's permissions will not help you invoke the secured activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare Notably, these bugged applications are from Google, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15979794/675674. By the way, that question says that the activity picker doesn't show the apps that require a permission, so a compromise option for me could be to start the picker and somehow get the activity that it resolves to. Also, thanks for pointing out `checkSelfPermission()`, I'll edit the question.

Comment: "that question says that the activity picker doesn't show the apps that require a permission" -- if that is the case, that is a relatively recent change, as it never used to do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did some tests: yes, it does filter them, and only since JB.

Comment: Maybe they listened to me after all. "so a compromise option for me could be to start the picker and somehow get the activity that it resolves to" -- that, however, is only available as of API Level 21 or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Level 22 has a version of [createChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender)) that lets you use the system activity chooser and receive the chosen activity in a broadcast.

In older versions the following method works:

```
List<ResolveInfo> candidates = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (int i = candidates.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = candidates.get(i);
    String permission = resolveInfo.activityInfo.permission;
    if (permission == null)
        permission = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.permission;
    if (permission != null && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        candidates.remove(i);
}
```